# reshape python concatenate text irregular dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, reshape, string-concatenation

I'm very new to Python and pandas in particular. I've got an irregular reshape problem where I want to concatenate all strings from one column of the dataframe where an id variable matches from the other column. It is an irregular reshape problem because the number of concatenations that need to be done may differ depending on the `id`.

So for example:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
df = pd.read_csv('sample.txt') 
print df 

   id text
0   1  ABC
1   1  BCD
2   2  CDE
3   2  DEF
4   2  EFG
5   3  FGH
```

I would like to use `id` to reshape, and concatenate all `text` for the cases where `id` matches, resulting in something like this: 
print(df_new):

```
   id         text
0   1      ABC BCD
1   2  CDE DEF EFG
2   3          FGH
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating `join`:

```
print (df.groupby('id')['text'].apply(' '.join).reset_index())
   id         text
0   1      ABC BCD
1   2  CDE DEF EFG
2   3          FGH
```

Comment: EKL If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions.